# MySQLi fetch_all Error with Consecutive Calls

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've set up a class to handle my MySQLi calls. The calls are working as they should, so no problems there.

I recently removed the result handling from my class's query method to two separate setter methods. There is now an error resulting from two consecutive `fetch_all` calls.

The previous (working) code with a single `fetch_all` call loads results into the two arrays `res_rows` and `res_cols`:

```
// Convert results into two sets of values
// and store in properties
// $res_rows=results by row (column names in element 0)
//           Each row is an indexed array 
// $res_cols=results by column (associative arrays)
//           Key is the column name; Value is an array

$results=$res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// $colNames is an array of the column names
$colNames=array_keys($results[0]);

// Rows
foreach($results as $r) {
    $this->res_rows[]=array_values($r);
}
array_unshift($this->res_rows,$colNames);

// Columns

$vals=array();

// Count the number columns in the query
$numCols=count($colNames);

// Iterate through the columns
for($i=0;$i<$numCols;$i++) {

    $col=$colNames[i];
    $storage=array();

    foreach($results as $r) {
        $storage[]=$r[$colNames[$i]];
    }

    $vals[]=$storage;
}

$this->res_cols=array_combine($colNames,$vals);
```

I've moved this code into two methods `setRes_rows` and `setRes_cols` and called them sequentially (see code). Each method pulls results from the result object using `fetch all`.

```
$this->setRes_rows($res);
$this->setRes_cols($res);
```

What happens is that the first call behaves as expected, and the second call returns an empty array.

If I reverse the calls (e.g. `setRes_cols` first), the same thing happens (first call works as expected; second call is empty). So I know the code is good. I even changed all the variable names in one of the methods with no effect.

I dumped all properties and methods on the result object between calls and it doesn't look like it changes. But for some reason that second `fetch_all` does not work.

The easy fix is for me to use a single `fetch_all` then call my methods. But I'm interested in knowing if there's anything weird I'm missing.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: I didn't find anything clear in the docs about how fetch_all sets the pointer, _BUT_ you could give it a try to do a `$res->data_seek(0)` before the second `fetch_all`

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. I didn't even think to reset the pointer.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then. Feel free to accept it, if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to reset the result pointer after a fetch_all.
I didn't find anything in the docs specifically for `fetch_all` - only about resetting after a `fetch_assoc()`, where we can find a reference to `data_seek()`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

So here's what you should do:

before the second `fetch_all()` do a

```
$res->data_seek(0);  // where $res is your mysqli result Object
```

This basicly sets the result pointer to the first record.

Comment: I managed to find a reference to the results pointer here: <http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php#85629>.

I really appreciate the help, Jeff. Thanks!